# Try to run a JavaScript file with Nashorn, failing due to problems with import/const/require

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

I need to add a new feature to my Java-8-based application (can't upgrade Java) where it takes an encoded string and decodes it to a JSON. The issue is that that decoding library is written in JavaScript, and the effort to convert the JavaScript code to Java could be consequential.

Looking into alternative solutions, I came across Nashorn, which supposedly is able to run Javascript code from Java. And so I tried to make it work.

First, I created a project with my `index.js" file containing an import statement and a function:

```json
import codec from "some-package"

function decode(a, b) {
   ...
}
```

I then installed the necessary packages through `npm -i` and ran my JavaScript code to verify that it worked by itself. Both `node index.js` and running the code through the right click action of VisualStudio ("Run Code") worked.

Then, I tried to make it work with Java. I moved all the files from my front project into the resources folder of Java, I created a test project with a `main()` function, and I wrote the following code:

```java
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine("--language=es6");

try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(Pulse4Decoder.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(DECODER_FILE_NAME)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        {
            engine.eval(reader);
        }
```

I then ran this code but got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:2:0 Expected an operand but found import
import codec from "some-package";
^ in <eval> at line number 2 at column number 0
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:537)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:150)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
    at com.edoreld.decoder.Pulse4Decoder.decode(Pulse4Decoder.java:30)
    at com.edoreld.decoder.Pulse4Decoder.main(Pulse4Decoder.java:20)
```

I thought the problem could be due to Nashorn requiring a specific form of the import statement, so I changed it to `const codec = require('@adeunis/codecs');`. However, this failed with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:150)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
    at com.edoreld.decoder.Pulse4Decoder.decode(Pulse4Decoder.java:30)
    at com.edoreld.decoder.Pulse4Decoder.main(Pulse4Decoder.java:20)
```

I googled both errors (which is how I came to use `--language=es6` in my code originally), but I wasn't able to make it work.

Are import/require statements not supported in Nashorn? How am I supposed to call a function in a JavaScript file that required a specific package if I can't make import/require to work?

Comment: Java 8-era Nashorn was a pretty old version of JavaScript.

Comment: Be that as it may, are there any ways of importing packages? Or perhaps there's a more modern alternative for Java 8? I looked into GraalVM but it looked a bit cumbersome to set up. However, I would prefer to keep it simple

Comment: Well I doubt there's *anything* "modern" for Java 8.

Comment: You could always  implement Java code that your JavaScript would call out to, and then that would read the file and inject it back into the script environment. It would be hard to make that work much like `require()` or `import`, especially if you want to use `npm` packages you've imported.

Comment: Also there are plenty of Java-based parsers for JSON.

Comment: Nashorn is now deprecated, find some alternative. Aside this, Nahsorn has several wrong limitations, and one of them is that you can't use JS frameworks or alike. Basic JS is roughly almost what you can use.